# Display message or block when View Page is null or empty

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have a `Content Type : Events` and i have created 3 events they are currently `published` and displayed in `Page` ie `Display as View`.
If there are no published `Events` then it should display a custom message as "No Events" or a "block".

I am trying to work on views with null values but i could not get it. Is there any thing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your configuration Views in the right you've "Advanced" zone, if you click on it you will see more options and "No results behavior" that will let you do what you want when the view doesn't return results.

[image]

Comment: Wow excellent, is there any ways to display a block.